# Tools to assess and instrument software quality (.net)

Tags: .net, build-process, nant

What tools/libraries do you run along with your build to assess and maintain quality?

As part of my CI (Cruise Control) builds I run:
[Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/)
[Nunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php)
[Ncover](http://www.ncover.com/)
[Ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)
[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx)
as part of [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

I am looking for tools to instrument complexities, metrics, etc   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also [dotProfiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and you can use buitin metric in visual studio team suite

Answer (score 2):

[ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I run as part of my regular build is Nunit, and some simple tweaks to deal with version maintenance.

My view is that the rest of the tools are useful *when trying to solve a specific problem*, but that you shouldn't spend all your time worrying about arbitrary numbers, "zone of pain", etc.

Don't get me wrong - I very much use the other tools (or variants of them, such as dotTrace) - but more "on demand" (with code coverage being the most regular that I use).

Comment: Marc, do you know that NDepend can help a lot churning code coverage data? See here: http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/04/09/make-the-most-of-your-test-coverage-data.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I just heard of [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) today on SO

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use some [NDepend's CQLinq rules](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) to address all facets of quality (metric, structure, coverage, evolution, side effects, dead code, naming coherence...). See the list of around 200 default CQLinq rules proposed [here](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html).

Answer (score 1):

One I saw yesterday
[Vil](http://www.1bot.com/features.html)

Answer (score 0):

UppercuT.

It uses the following to analyze code:

- NUnit OR MbUnit
- NCover
- NDepend

UppercuT uses NAnt to build and it is the insanely easy to use Build Framework!

http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/

Some good explanations here: [UppercuT](http://ferventcoder.com/category/uppercut.aspx)